# Rails custom routing not keeping URL's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, controller, routes

I'm trying to add custom routes to my application but starting by keeping it simple.

I wish to end up with a url like:

> /gallery/holidays/america/california

with each of 'holiday', 'america' and 'california' being an instance of my `Collection` model.

For now, I have not implemented slugs to use in the URL so at the moment the URL's need to be:

> /gallery/594/595/597

with each number being the id of a collection.

Now, I have added the following route to my routing file:

```
get '/gallery/*path' => 'Gallery#splitUrl'
```

and the corresponding action is currently:

```
  def splitUrl
    path_parts = params[:path].split('/')

    puts path_parts[1]

    # Deal with last item of the URL
    last_item = path_parts.last

    redirect_to Collection.find(last_item) if (Collection.find_by_id(last_item))
  end
```

I know it's basic so far but just starting out with implementing it. It is redirecting to the appropriate collection. In the code above it is taking me to collection with id of 597 but when it does so, the URL in the address bar changes to /collections/597. How can I keep it being the /gallery/594/595/597 style?

At the end of building my app the gallery urls should be like:

/gallery/holidays/america/california/day1/

Not decided whether to actually have the individual photo on a page of it's own but if I do then it needs to be at the end of the url.

I have several models for the gallery:

Collection
Album
Photo
PhotoSize

Collections can contain other collections OR albums but NEVER both.

I don't think I am going about this in the right way but just can't see what the right way to solve this is.

I also don't wish the /collections/ URL's to work as I want people to have to go throguh the full URL to access them.

I have tried telling the splitUrl method to render the collection#show template and created the instance variables that it requires but the rendering of the template fails as partials that the template includes are not able to be located and also as some of my styling is based on the controller name and action it fails as the new controller and action are now gallery and splitUrl.

If anyone has any ideas on how to get this to all work out then i'd highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use `get '/gallery/:holiday/:country/:state`=> 'Gallery#splitUrl'

Comment: Thanks. I should have explained, I can't use a simple route like that as the collections could be unlimited in depth (they'll be kept sensible) but are not always holiday, country and state.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to use `redirect_to`, just call a method to manipulate/render the collection right at end of the `splitUrl`.

If you do the redirect, it will generate another URL that is send to browser, and then the browser will ask your server to serve the new URL. If your server redirect to the same URL, this will generate a endless loop.

See more at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to and at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

---

Edit using `show`method:

One way is you manage the collection in `show` method, like:

```
def show
  @collection = getCollection
  ...
end

def getCollection
  # find collection by id, if url is like /collection_id
  return Collection.find(param[:id]) if param[:id]

  # find collection with last id, if request is like /id1/id2/id3
  path_parts = params[:path].split('/')
  Collection.find(path_parts.last)
end
```

Comment: I would use `render` but to my Collection Show needs other instance variables set which the page needs. I need it run go to the Collection#Show action but keeping the URL. I'm starting to think that I am not going the right way here somehow. I think my confusion comes from the fact that Collection is a self referential model and I need them to have the /collection1/collection2/collection3/collection4... style url's. I then need to put it all under the /gallery url.  Any ideas?

Comment: The basic ideia is that you dont need to redirect. So you can try send to `Collection#show` and look if the `param[:id]` is a kind of `collection1/collection2/coll3...`, then you manage all collections in `show`. After you got this working you can think in refactor `show` to have a better code.

Comment: What do you mean by send to?

Comment: Just tried a few ideas using the splitUrl action I have in my gallery controller and tried a url which should show a collections show view. I made sure the require instance variables were available for the template and rendered template: "collections/show" but I get errors stating that the partials I have used within the template cannot be located as it is looking under gallery and they don't exist there. Also, the action in params shows as splitUrl which is logical but as some of my styling is based on that, it fails. I still think I am not doing this correctly? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just added more details in the second half of my OP